# How to get the length or size of a specific dimensioned array

Tags: vba

I am looking for something like this:

Say I have a 1D array i.e. myArray(0 to 5) and assigned to each indexed array as follows:

myArray(0) = "C"  
myArray(1) = "A"  
myArray(2) = "A B"  
myArray(3) = "A C"  
MyArray(4) = "B C"  
MyArray(5) = "A B C"

I wanted to find the size of an array element for example MyArray(5) and gives me the answer as 3 because it contains three characters A,B and C.

I couldn't find the answer as I wanted. Many answers suggested using UBound function, but this will not giving me what I want. Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To get the number of letters in a value** :

```
Sub CountLetters(theText as string)
    Dim tab() As String
    Dim i as integer
    dim nb as integer
    tab = split(theText)
    For i = 0 To UBound(tab)
        'if the uppercase caracter ascii code is above or equal 65 (code for "A") and below 90 (code for "Z"), we count it
        if ((asc(ucase(tab(i))) >= 65) and (asc(ucase(tab(i))) =< 90)) then
             nb = nb + 1
        end if
    Next i
    CountLetters = nb
End Sub
```

**To get the number of elements not blank** (different of space) :

```
Sub CountNotBlankElements(theText as string)
    Dim tab() As String
    Dim i as integer
    dim nb as integer
    tab = split(theText)
    For i = 0 To UBound(tab)
        'if the caracter ascii is not a space, we count it
        if (tab(i) <> " ") then
             nb = nb + 1
        end if
    Next i
    CountNotBlankElements = nb
End Sub
```

Examples :

```
Msgbox CountLetters(MyArray(5))
Msgbox CountNotBlankElements(MyArray(5))
```

Comment: Thanks Veve with an interesting codes of yours. Appreciate your effort to help. I will try it as well and I've learned something today. Appreciate it so much. I will definitely come back to this wonderful community. Have a productive day ahead.

Comment: Dear Vive, sorry for the late reply to your comment. Yes you are right, as what i have mentioned in my Answer post of this thread, that my string contains 5 element in it (including spacebar) but I only need to count the alphabets only. And it turns out that your codes give me what i wanted (with some modifications). Wonderful and thanks again.

Comment: Vive, yes, I accept both answers. However, your answer seems to work for me since it took care of the spaces between the characters within the string. See the ANSWER given by me in this thread (I posted my answer). I use your codes with some minor modifications (to suite my work). Thanks Vive for your valuable insight.

Comment: Vive, I believe, I posted the answer using your code with some minor modification (to suite my work). Did you see them?

Comment: Vive, I changed it to be a 'Function' instead of a 'Sub', but most of your codes were not change. And it WORKED for me!.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim str(1) As String
    str(0) = "Hello"
    str(1) = "and"

    For i = LBound(str) To UBound(str)
        MsgBox (Len(str(i)))
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Appreciate your fast feedback ruedi, and I've tried it, but it was not giving me the result that I am looking for. I am looking for something like finding the length of str(1) which will give me the answer of 3 because it contains three characters ('a','n' and 'd'). Something like that. Appreciate if you help me further on that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: my code will give you the answer 5 and 3. 5 is the length of 'Hello' and '3 is the length of 'and'. Maybe I am not getting it but is that not what you are looking for finding the length of the string elements?

Comment: I confirm that the code provided by Ruedi will returns exactly what you asked for. Even after having read 2 times both your question and your comment above, I don't really understand what else you are looking for.

Comment: My deepest apology ruedi and Thomas. Yap, I got It. The fist time I ran reudi's code, I get the answer of 6 (I wonder why?). But when I ran it again, I get the answers that I wanted. Thanks a lot guys. You are my Saviors.

Comment: To Veve, appreciate your 'full of insight' codes. I will try your codes as well. I've learned something today. Thanks a lot guys.

Comment: In rudi code the number of characters in a string is calculated .  I understood you wanted to get the number of letters or elements not blank. I may have misunderstood but with the string "A B C" you should get 3 as result right ?

Comment: You welcome. Could you please make the answer so ozher people know the problem is solved.

Comment: Dear reudi, sorry for the late reply. I forgot that my string contains a spacebar, with your codes, it will count the spacebar as well. I'd implemented as what Vive suggested and it gives me what I want. However, if you have any code simpler/shorter than that, it would be much appreciated. Thanks a lot for your codes. I've learned something as well.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out later that my string has got a space between them. So when I applied ruedi's code again by adding a space between the string, say: "a_n_d" (underscore denotes a spacebar), it gives me the answer of 5 and not 3.

I tried Veve's code with some modifications (to suite my work) as follows:

Sub main_body()
'some codes

dim a as integer
a = CountNotBlankElements(maResult(f))
'maResult(f) is my specific global array containing the text
'I assigned the index as a global variable f

'some codes
End sub

Function CountNotBlankElements(Optional ByVal theText As Variant)

Dim tab1() As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim nb As Integer
    'tab1 = Split(theText)
    tab1 = Split(maResult(f))
    For i = 0 To UBound(tab1)
        'if the caracter ascii is not a space, we count it
        If (tab1(i) <> " ") Then
             nb = nb + 1
        End If
    Next i
    CountNotBlankElements = nb

End Function

So, I can use variable 'a' for other purpose.
Thanks a lot guys, good enough for me.
Appreciate it.